# How to add next & previous option to a slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I used this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/) to create a simple jquery slider:

HTML (Wrapper with div's as the "slides", which can contain any content):

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS (Slides need to be absolutely positioned within the wrapper. This has a tiny bit of extra pizazz):

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

JQUERY(Run after DOM is ready):

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

And question is: how add next & previous option to this slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i created a working code jsfiddle link [next-prev button slider](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/v7639/1/).

// Add two links to HTML
HTML:

```
   <a id="prev" href="#" >Prev</a>  
   <a id="next" href="#" >Next</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(1000)
     $('#slideshow > div:last-child')
    .prependTo('#slideshow') 
    .fadeOut();
    $('#slideshow > div:first-child').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: i have added next and prev links.. click on it it will move to next image. For sliding automatically i have set high value in settimeout function, u can change it to 5000.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/v7639/1/  Enabled auto sliding with 5 seconds delay

Comment: I don't know where i did wrong!! but is still not working for me!!! I'm just copy/paste the codes in my page, all things work good but next/prev links didn't work!!

Comment: how's that possible,, i see fiddle working. Are you talking about fiddle or your implementation is not working ? are you able to view next and prev buttons in fiddle output ? its aligned in botton

Comment: It's working in fiddle but in a page, is not! yes, i see the links.

Comment: make sure that you put click functions inside $(document).ready function.

Comment: It's Work. Thank you Dave. It was my bad, i'm didn't put $(document).ready function.